# Resolving ArcSDE for Oracle 11g Layer not found (-20) error?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

I am using ArcSDE for Oracle 11g, with Oracle spatial database. I use the sdelayer command ot register my feature class. Surprisingly I get this error of **Layer not found(-20)** error. The table does exist in Oracle and I had configured feature classes using the same data source.

An **[Esri Technical Article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/16168)** suggests to increase tablespace, but I do have free spaces in my tablespace.

Please advise me on this?

Answer (score 1):

ArcSDE is in the running for some of the most useless, least helpful error codes I've ever seen.

I'm not sure your link will help much here as they're using sdeimport - you're simply registering.

You may however wish to try this thread:
http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=2&f=59&t=61938

This thread may also help:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/15499-Setting-permission-on-feature-dataset-with-sdelayer-don-t-work